# How to switch between layouts in android?

Tags: android

I am making a contact list application, and i have a main screen that helps you save a contact. I have a search button there. Then i created another UI that i call it search screen.  When i click on the search button on main screen, i want to be redirected to the other UI, i.e. search screen. I am planning to add setOnClickListener method for search button but how can i switch from main screen to search screen when i click the button?

```
btn_goSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        ?????????

        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Currentactivity, YourSearcgActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured out how to do

Answer (score 0):

you should create another `Activity`, maybe call it SearchActivity, and when the user clicks the button, just start SearchActivity with a simple intent, that will load its own layout and everything:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context,SearchActivty.class));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how will the activity understand which UI to load?

Comment: every `Activity` has `onCreate()` function, that loads the approproate UI with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);`, and you need to create layout called "activity_search" in your layout folder.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out how to do